# Change the color of three.line on button click three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js, I have been trying to change the color of the line when a button is clicked which I have created using line basic material, but the color of the line is not getting changed.

**my code**

```
if (color === "color") {
        material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000,
            opacity: 1,
            linewidth: 5
        });


    } else {
        material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x000000,
            opacity: 1,
            linewidth: 1
        });

    }

    var tmp_geo = new THREE.Geometry();
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 0 ));
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 10 ));

    line = new THREE.Line(tmp_geo, material);

    line.material.needsUpdate = true;
    line.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

    line.scale.x = line.scale.y = line.scale.z = 1;
    line.originalScale = 1;
    geometries.push(tmp_geo);

    scene.add(line);
```

I am using webGlRenderer with Trackball controls and my version is r66. Is there anyway to do this. I have been trying to find a solution to fix this. Please any help will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you trying to do? trying to change material or material color on clicking the button?

Comment: Material color i.e color of the line which I have created for highlighting the path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script only init material to the scene, if you want to change material in live scene, you must set material again.

Just call onclick by function

```
line.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );         
line.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Can you post JS fiddle? there will be problem in another part.

Comment: Sorry Martin, actually your code changed the entire line objects that I have created in my page, but I need to change the color of the particular line object when a object associated with line is clicked. Hence I created a line name for each line object I have created and highlighted the line by using those name, I acheived this by using   **var line = scene.getObjectByName(linename);** and followed by your code.Thank you for your suggestion. Is that clear? Martin

Comment: This is possible solution, but have in mind, in each cycle scene.getObjectByName must list all items in scene, if you have animation, it is 40-60 per sec.
But better solution depends on construction of your aplication.

Comment: Martin, what is the best approach for getting the better solution that you are refering? thank you in  advance

Comment: It depends on chain of events causing needs of color switching.  I understand you know which lines is associated in which objects before you load the scene. If you changing lines in some visual connection with object, in initialization of this object make connection first. Best will be associate line into parent object and call not a line by name but child line of affected object. Or you can find another approach how to simple identify lines instead of searching all object again and again. And more solutions  much simply for code handling ...

Comment: Thank you for making clear Martin, I will look to get the reliable solution to get the better approach instead of searching all the objects again and again. **Best will be associate line into parent object and call not a line by name but child line of affected object** will be best approach I hope.I will look into it. Thank you Martin. However for now I got the result :-)

Answer (score 2):

here find the example link [Change color](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/Lfr5my2s/)

```
onClick = function() {
line.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff * Math.random());
line.material.needsUpdate = true;
};
```

If the example is not clear please share your code in jsfiddle so that i can help you.

Comment: Example is so clear.Thank you for sharing the answer.Similar thing I have executed in my code, problem is am having multiple number of line and want to highlight particular lines associated with the object when a click is made on the object.So I named each line and achieved the result by executing the code which I shared above. is there anything wrong in my code? Thank you so much user2089677

Comment: Are you trying to change color of the line by clicking the line object(i.e. intersected line with the mouse pointer)

Comment: No, I have connected the multiple objects(like cube,cylinder) with line objects. When I click on the objects, by then I need to change colour of the line associated with that object.Is that clear?  user2089677

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether it is correct or wrong, but I got the result by just adding a name to a line (line.name = "line name") and

```
    var  material;
    if (color === "color") {

        var lineColorChange = scene.getObjectByName(linename);
        lineColorChange.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff00ff);
        line.geometry.dynamic = true;
        line.material.overdraw = true;
        lineColorChange.material.needsUpdate = true;

    } else {
        material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x000000,
            opacity: 1,
            linewidth: 5
        });

    }

    var tmp_geo = new THREE.Geometry();
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(10,0,10);
    tmp_geo.vertices.push(-10,0,-10);

    line = new THREE.Line(tmp_geo, material);
    line.name = linename;


    geometries.push(tmp_geo);
    scene.add(line);
```